# Warning in install.packages : package ‘rattle’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)

Tags: r, rattle

I was trying to `install.packages("rattle")`
but it shows this :

```
Installing package into ‘/home/shahin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rattle’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

I am in ubuntu 18.04. I also tried to install RGtk2 that also shows error. How can i install rattle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rattle` **requires** R version **3.5.0** or higher](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rattle/index.html).

Update R to the latest version, then you'll be able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `R` version following these instructions : [Ubuntu Packages for R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html). Pay attention to the **Secure APT** section.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands in order to update your version:

`install.packages("installr")`

`library(installr)`

`updateR()`

This will start the updating process of your R installation by: “finding the latest R version, downloading it, running the installer, deleting the installation file, copy and updating old packages to the new R installation.”

Comment: I didn't get it actually, how should i update R version from 3.4.4 to 3.5.0 or higher? Can you give some elaborate answer please.

Comment: please run these commands which I have mentioned in my answer. I have edited the same.

Comment: it tried to run it but it shows package 'installr' is not available for R version 3.4.4

Comment: try this : `install.packages("stringi")` then   `require(installr)`. If this does not work then reinstall with this link https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/

Comment: unfortunately it also didn't work and tried to reinstall and install 3.5.0 but my system don't take that also :( anyway, thanks for your help, i moved in python for my task, R is not working fine for me.